# Can I use nVidia CUDA on QNX(x86 or tegra) and what driver do I need for this?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, qnx, tegra

Can I use nVidia CUDA on QNX(x86_64 or other) and what driver do I need for this?

I found nothing about this by link, and in #46 answer sound like "I don't know"
http://www.qnx.com/news/web_seminars/faq_multicore.html

But, QNX thinks to Include Support for NVIDIA Tegra Processor Family:
http://www.qnx.com/news/pr_5306_1.html

And nVidia thinks to add support CUDA and OpenCL to the nVidia Tegra5(Logan) ARM+GK1xx in next year:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegra#Logan

http://www.ubergizmo.com/2013/07/nvidia-tegra-5-release-date-specs-news/

And then can we use CUDA on nVidia Tegra5(ARM+GK1xx) on QNX(ARM), and what about QNX(x86)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure QNX isn't Linux. In Linux nvidia hardware is supported through a binary blob, that you download and install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, there's no support for CUDA on QNX.
The supported operating systems for CUDA are listed on the [cuda download page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) as well as in section 1.4 of the [release notes](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/5_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes.pdf)

Regarding Tegra, at this time there are no Tegra devices that support CUDA.  The list of CUDA-enabled GPUs is [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus).  Whether using an x86/x86_64 CPU or an ARM CPU, one of these CUDA GPUs is required for CUDA support.

Update: There are now tegra devices that support CUDA, including the widely available Tegra TK1 and recently announced TX1.